# Seeing Google Chrome from Mac icon in the dock

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

I have two macs running on my desk. Now when I switch to Chrome on 1st of them, on 2nd it shows an icon looking like this in the dock:

[image: Google Chrome from Mac]

Sometimes it hides itself, and works that way only, not vice versa for opening Chrome on 2nd and seeing that notification on 1st.

What is it made for and where can I find more info on it?

Comment: Is there a way to disable this only for Chrome? I want to keep many Handoff features (such as Shared Clipboard), but *not* everything offering to open a URL in my Dock.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is [Handoff](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6153783?hl=en), part of the [Continuity features](https://www.apple.com/osx/continuity/) in 10.10 Yosemite. In this case, with Google Chrome, your open tabs are shared between computers, so you can continue browsing when switching devices.

To turn off Handoff on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, go to Settings > General > Handoff & Suggested Apps, and turn off Handoff. On your Mac, go to System Preferences > General and uncheck the Allow Handoff setting.

Comment: External links can become unavailable, in which case you answer would have little value.  Please include the essential information in your answer and use the link for reference.

Comment: Ok, so why am I seeing tabs from my *wife's* iPad on *my* Mac account ?

Answer (score 14):

I think in your Mac you can find it. Here is how I managed to disable it on my Mac. [image: Turn it off in Mac OS X]

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: You could have just edited @user21762's answer since those instructions are exactly identical to how you got there.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you start composing an email on your mac 1. You walk into the room with mac 2. You can finish composing the email on mac 2 by clicking the chrome symbol. It will even work with iPhone's, iPad s, iPods, etc.

There is an article on it [here](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/132442-chrome-browser-for-ios-now-supports-os-x-s-handoff-feature).